# .net 8 AddHttpClient not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I'm registering my HttpClient like this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyClass, MyClass>(i =>
    {
        i.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com"); //breakpoint here never stops
    });
```

And `MyClass`'s constructor is implemented like

```
public MyClass(HttpClient client)
{
    // client.BaseAddress is null here
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My expectation here is the `client` on the concrete class comes pre-configured...

I have already tried registering like:

- `AddHttpClient("global", i => { i.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com"); }`
- `AddHttpClient<MyClass>(i => { i.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com"); }`
- `AddHttpClient<IMyClass>(i => { i.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://google.com"); }`

Comment: I tested in .net8, it works as expected not null.

Comment: I created a small example by using your code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/G0piWs working like expected

Comment: @Leonardo Please make sure you post [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can help you. Please include other pieces of code that you think can help others understand the issue, e.g. other HttpClient registrations, or MyClass registration within the DI container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue while writing unit tests, and the cause is internal service registration introduced with .NET 8. See here: [DefaultHttpClientBuilder - dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.0/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/DefaultHttpClientBuilder.cs)

They're trying to resolve that tracker class, using LINQ `.Single()` method, because they aren't expecting that registered class is not present.

I've currently disabled that specific unit test, but I'm sorry that does not solve your issue at all because they broke it (.NET 7 and earlier versions do not have this issue.)